# how i can get the height of a red black tree and not the black height

Tags: c

im trying to get the height of a red black tree that inserted in it a file of 3000+ word and it gives me a height = 1968 i dont know if the error in the insertion part or the algorithm of calculating the height

the function for height

```
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))
int height(Node* Root)
{
    int h = 0;

    if (Root != NULL) {
        if (Root == T_Nil)
            h = 1;
        else
        {
            int leftHeight  = height(Root->left);
            int rightHeight = height(Root->right);
            h = MAX(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
        }
    }

    return h;
}
```

Having :

```
typedef struct Node {
 char word[128];
 char color;
 struct Node * left;
 struct Node *right;
 struct Node *parent; 
} Node;

struct Node T_Nil_Node;
Node * T_Nil = &T_Nil_Node;
```

insert function

```
 void redBlackInsert(Node** T, char word[128])
   {
   Node* z =  newNode(word);
   Node* y =  T_Nil;
   Node* x = *T;
   while (x != T_Nil)
   {
      y = x;
      if (strcmp(z->word,x->word)<0)
        x = x->left;
      else
        x = x->right;
   }

   z->parent = y;
   if (y == T_Nil)
     *T = z;
   else if (strcmp(z->word,y->word)<0)
      y->left  = z;
   else
      y->right = z;

   z->left  = T_Nil;
   z->right = T_Nil;
   z->color = RED;
   redBlackInsertFixup(T, z);
}
```

fixup functin

```
 void redBlackInsertFixup(Node** Root, Node* New)
 {
Node* temp;
while (New->parent->color == RED)
{
    if (New->parent == New->parent->parent->left)
    {
        temp = New->parent->parent->right;
        if (temp->color == RED)
        {
            New->parent->color = BLACK;
            temp->color = BLACK;
            New->parent->parent->color = RED;
            New = New->parent->parent;
        }
        else
        {
            if (New == New->parent->right)
            {
                New = New->parent;
                rotateLeft(Root, New);
            }
            New->parent->color = BLACK;
            New->parent->parent->color = RED;
            rotateRight(Root, New->parent->parent);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        temp = New->parent->parent->left;
        if (temp->color == RED)
        {
            New->parent->color = BLACK;
            New->color = BLACK;
            New->parent->parent->color = RED;
            New = New->parent->parent;
        }
        else
        {
            if (New == New->parent->left)
            {
                New = New->parent;
                rotateRight(Root, New);
            }
            New->parent->color = BLACK;
            New->parent->parent->color = RED;
            rotateLeft(Root, New->parent->parent);
        }
    }
}
Root[0]->color = BLACK;
 }
```

rotating left

```
  void rotateLeft( Node** T, Node* x)
 {
  Node *y  = x->right;
x->right = y->left;
if (y->left != T_Nil)
    y->left->parent = x;
y->parent = x->parent;
if (x->parent == T_Nil)
    *T = y;
else if (x == x->parent->left)
    x->parent->left = y;
else
    x->parent->right = y;
y->left   = x;
x->parent = y;
 }
```

rotating right (i use it in fix up)

```
void rotateRight(Node** T, Node* y)
{
Node *x  = y->left;
y->left  = x->right;
if (x->right != T_Nil)
    x->right->parent = y;
x->parent = y->parent;
if (y->parent == T_Nil)
    *T = x;
else if (y == y->parent->right)
    y->parent->right = x;
else
    y->parent->left  = x;
x->right  = y;
y->parent = x;
  }
```

Comment: The distinction between `NULL` and `T_Nil` has a [bad smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) to it, but otherwise that code looks ok.

Comment: What value for the height of the tree are you expecting to get?

Comment: im expecting 21 @MarkBenningfield

Comment: What is the T_Nil part doing

Comment: typedef struct Node
{
    char word[128];
    char color;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *parent;
} Node;

struct Node  T_Nil_Node;
Node* T_Nil = &T_Nil_Node;      @4386427

Comment: @codiins You need to post more code - we need to see the insert function. Don't post it in a comment. Instead edit the question and add the code in the question.

Comment: It looks like your tree is not balanced.

Comment: What is `T_Nil` supposed to be? If it is some kind of sentinel to avoid having to make a special case out of `NULL`, why is it treated differently than `NULL` (and, indeed, why is `NULL` made into a special case)? For example, it seems that both `T_Nil` and `NULL` should return 0, whereas here they return 1 and 0, respectively.

Comment: @codiins BTW - The code you posted in the comment is wrong. The `struct Node left;` is missing a `*`

Comment: @codiins when you add information edit your question, do not use a remark as you did for `typedef struct Node ...`

Comment: @4386427 `Node T_Nil = &T_Nil_Node;` is wrong too and must be `Node * T_Nil = &T_Nil_Node;`

Comment: @bruno True but ... It's probably better to tell OP than tell me :-)

Comment: @4386427 the OP is warn when any remark is added, so I also tell the OP

Comment: @bruno: that's markdown at work, and another reason not to paste code into comments.

Comment: im sry for not posting the code i edited it now

Comment: You probably want to debug with a lot less than 3000 words. e.g. put 5 or 10 words into your tree and then output the tree structure to the console to verify it's correct, and work through the individual rebalancing cases to make sure they all work correctly.

Comment: i put 5 words and it gave me height of 5 , i didnt get the console part @Rup

Comment: Based on the additional code posted, I'm not entirely sure the benefits of `T_Nil` outweigh the issues. The only thing you are really gaining from it is the ability to do `->parent->color` and `->parent->parent` without checking for `NULL`, but it seems quite fragile (e.g., you are assigning the color of the single `T_Nil` node) and requires that you make the `parent` link of `T_Nil` circular, pointing to itself, or the `->parent->parent` breaks…

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong

```
   if (Root == T_Nil)
        h = 1;
```

I'd expect it to look like this

```
   if (Root->right == NULL && Root->left ==  NULL)
       h = 1;
```

This is a node that has no children and thus has height of 1.

> The function looks like it would work without this if statement since a null value to the function return 0. Since it already has the +1 after the MAX I'm guessing this is the more correct solution.

Comment: warning in red-black tree all the nodes have 2 children being other nodes or nil (nil does not count for the height)

Comment: @bruno -- you do understand that nil and NULL are the same thing?

Comment: no they are not the same, NULL is 0 but T_Nil is the address of a special node ( `struct Node T_Nil_Node; Node * T_Nil = &T_Nil_Node;`)

Comment: OP is apparently using a `T_Nil` instance as a signal for a terminal leaf node (with no children)

Comment: @bruno -- you are talking about a "sentinel node"?  Then just put that in the if statement above -- you would never have two types of "blank" leaf nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing up NULL and a sentinel NIL node in your `height` function. Either you use NULL for representing "no childern" or you use a sentinel NIL object. Having both at the same time seems wrong.

Besides that it seems wrong to return 1 when a sentinel is reached.

Here is how I would expect the code to be...

**Using sentinel NIL** (which it seems you want to do)

```
int height(Node* Root)
{
    assert(Root != NULL);          // NULL is never allowed
    if (Root == T_Nil) return 0;   // No data here so return 0

    int leftHeight  = height(Root->left);
    int rightHeight = height(Root->right);
    int h = MAX(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
    return h;
}
```

**Using NULL** (which it seems you don't want to do)

```
int height(Node* Root)
{
    if (Root == NULL) return 0;   // No data here so return 0

    int leftHeight  = height(Root->left);
    int rightHeight = height(Root->right);
    int h = MAX(leftHeight, rightHeight) + 1;
    return h;
}
```

Comment: it gave me the same height which is wrong i think there is something wrong with the insertion , what do you think?  @4386427

Comment: @codiins well.. I can't really say much about the insertion as you still haven't posted all code. For instance we can't see `redBlackInsertFixup`. Also we can't see what your `MAX` is doing... so again.. edit your question and give all code we need. Also... can you make it fail with a short input file? Then post that file as well.